# Python And Groovy Functions Options

Tags: python, groovy

I have a python script which extracts values from json object , for which the main function i use is `json.loads()`.

Now i need the same script to be written in Groovy, so is there any function in Groovy which is equivalent to `json.loads` in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)?

ie:

```
import groovy.json.*

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('{"person":{"name":"Guillaume","age":33,"pets":["dog","cat"]}}')

assert result.person.name == 'Guillaume'
```

Comment: well i tried it but am not able to extract the value from it.

Comment: @user2957389 Maybe if you posted the code you are trying in the question, I could say for sure?

Comment: the code which you have written is the same as mine.But i want to extract that "Guillaume" and store in string.

Comment: @user2957389 To get `Guillaume` as a String, you should be able to do `result.person.name`